getting Cannot parse the request InvalidRequestFormat when creating azure vm
I am running below script to create azure vm
Connect-AzAccount

$cred = Get-Credential

$vm = New-AzVMConfig -VMName "MyVirtualVM" -VMSize "Standard_D1"

$vm = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName "MyVM" -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate

$vm = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Offer "WindowsServer" -Skus "2016-Datacenter" -Version "latest"

$vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name "MyOSDisk" -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption FromImage -Caching ReadWrite

$vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id "/subscriptions/{subscriptionid}/resourceGroups/myresource/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/myresource-vnet"

New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "Prod-IT" -Location "EastUS" -VM $vm


After running the script getting below error
New-AzVM : Cannot parse the request.
ErrorCode: InvalidRequestFormat
ErrorMessage: Cannot parse the request.
ErrorTarget: 
StatusCode: 400
ReasonPhrase: 
OperationID : 22637114-2ddd-49c2-a4b1-3748ac166e12
At line:15 char:1
+ New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "Prod-IT" -Location "EastUS" -VM $vm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand

Please help where I am going wrong. Thanks

In your script, I notice that you're not specifying a network interface ID for the VM. You can either pass the existing NIC ID or create a new one using the following command.
$nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "MyNIC" -ResourceGroupName "Prod-IT" -Location "EastUS" -Subnet $subnet

You are right. I am not passing network interface id. after passing it. The script ran successful. thanks for the help


New-AzVM : Cannot parse the request.

When I try to execute your script, I also get the same error as below.

The error you are encountering is due to passing an invalid NIC ID
To resolve the issue, ensure that you pass the valid NIC ID under the command Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id. If there is no NIC, create a new one and attach it to the VM.
Here is the updated PowerShell Script to create a VM
    Connect-AzAccount
    
    $cred = Get-Credential
    
    $vnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name "myresource-vnet" -ResourceGroupName "myresource"
    
    $subnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name "default" -VirtualNetwork $vnet
    
    $nic = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "MyNIC" -ResourceGroupName "Prod-IT" -Location "EastUS" -Subnet $subnet
    
    $vm = New-AzVMConfig -VMName "MyVirtualVM" -VMSize "Standard_D1"
    
    $vm = Set-AzVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName "MyVM" -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
    
    $vm = Set-AzVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName "MicrosoftWindowsServer" -Offer "WindowsServer" -Skus "2016-Datacenter" -Version "latest"
    
    $vm = Set-AzVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name "MyOSDisk" -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption FromImage -Caching ReadWrite
    
    $vm = Add-AzVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id
    
    New-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "Prod-IT" -Location "EastUS" -VM $vm

Output:

After running the PowerShell script, the VM has been created successfully.

